# What's the contract for a BroadcastReceiver of PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I see that a BroadcastReceiver has a `result_code`, `result_data`, and `extras` which the broadcaster can use to decide what to do next.

In the case of the broadcaster for the `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` intent, **where can I read** (link please) the written contract as to what it's registered BroadcastReceivers are supposed to do (and can do) to affect the broadcaster's behavior?

I apologize for the newbie question. I am only a few days into learning android and I have searched the android docs but have not found anything so far.

Thanks!